# Lectura de variables en un proceso C

Tags: c, variables, proceso

He estado intentando crear un programa en C que despliegue un menú y dependiendo de la opción elegida se cree un proceso hijo con otro menú de opciones de comida, pero al entrar al proceso hijo no puedo leer variables y directamente se brinca esa instrucción.
Esta es la función que despliega el menú de la comida:

```
void Desayuno(){

int pedido = 0;

printf("Para el desayuno tenemos: \n");
printf("1)Cereal\n2)Hotcakes\n3)Huevos al gusto\n4)Sincronizadas\n5)Enchiladas\n");
printf("Que desea ordenar? \n");
scanf(" %d", &pedido);
printf("%d", pedido);}
```

Este es el main donde se crean el proceso hijo:

```
    int pid, opcion;
char nombre[20];


    printf("Ingrese su nombre: ");
    //scanf("%s", nombre);
    printf("1)Desayuno\n2)Comida\n3)Cena\n4)Desayuno y comida\n5)Desayuno y cena\n6)Comida y cena\n7)Los tres\n");
    printf("Que menu(s) desea ver?\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);

    switch(opcion){

        case 1:
                if(fork() == 0)
                    Desayuno();
        break;
```

[image: En donde debería leer la opción de la comida deseada es donde se brinca el scanf]
¿Alguna idea de porque se brinca el scanf? He intentado usando getchar y fflush para limpiar el buffer como cuando se leen caracteres, pero no me funcionó hacer eso. Gracias por su ayuda =D

Comment: Por favor publica un [mcve]. Estás usando Windows?

Comment: No entiendo, en que parte del código se brinca el printf? ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo donde se refleje el problema?

Comment: Estoy trabajando en Ubuntu 20.04, ya agregué una captura de como se brinca el scanf para pedir la comida deseada, gracias por sugerirme agregar la captura =D

Comment: No se brinca el scanf. El segundo proceso todavía está esperando su entrada. Estás viendo el indicador del shell porque el primer proceso ha finalizado. El shell no sabe nada sobre el segundo proceso.